# how to awk specific characters from string in windows word file

Tags: awk, cygwin

I have a word document and I want to pick only the lines which begin with an integer. i have cygwin and want to use awk command to pick the entire line...

the command i am using is awk /n/ document1 but it is pulling lines with "n" alphabet for me.

eg :

```
129 CalledVPNTop-
GroupNumber
Char[15] Indicates the top group number of the called party.
Value range: numerals within 0-9
Can be null
130 CalledVPNGrou
pNumber
Char[10] Indicates the group number of the called party.
Value range: numerals within 0-9
Can be null
131 CalledVPNShor
tNumber
Char[10] Indicates the short number of the called party
Value range: numerals within 0-9
Can be null
132 CallingNetwork
Type
Char[10] Reserved.
Can be null
133 CalledNetwork-
Type
Char[10] Reserved.
Can be null
134 GroupCallType Char[10] Indicates the call type when the charged subscriber
is a VPN user.
The options are as follows:
l 0: On-net call
l 1: Off-net call
l Other: to be extended
```

I want to pick up the characters beginning with integers like 129, 130, 131, and the next 11 characters after that. any help would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/^[0-9]+/{print substr($0,length($1),11)}' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

With a text file I would use `awk '/^[:digit:]*/ {print $0}' document.txt`.

Comment: i tried awk '/^[:0-9:]*/ {print $0}' Document1.txt but i am picking the entire sheet

Comment: You have to use either `[0-9]` (the range of digits) or `[:digit:]` (the whole set).

Comment: @sarathi is right, you need also to change the `*` with a `+`. My bad.

Comment: No need for `{print $0}`, that's the default action.

Comment: @EdMorton, you're right, I'm just used to write it explicitly :D

Comment: You could wrap the whole script in a `while (getline)` loop, wrap the condition tests in explicit `if`s, and call split($0,flds,FS) to create an array of fields too. My point is just that it's not good practice to manually code the the things that awk does for you automatically. By the way `/[:digit:]/` matches the characters :, d, i, g, and t - you want `/[[:digit:]]/` to match all digits.

Comment: @EdMorton You are absolutely right. Damn I'm rusty with awk... :D